# Adding wifi nfs boot to initramfs, under armbian and uboot

Tags: nfs, initramfs, u-boot, netboot, armbian

I'm trying to setup my an initramfs image to nfs boot from a WPA wifi access point. My image is working with armbian and uboot.

so far I have NFS booting over ethernet just fine. But no real path to follow on the idea of getting all the right software, drivers, modules and scripts onto the initramfs image or even which are the right software,drivers,modules, scripts.

For hardware I have 35 OrangePi Zero 
- [manufacture link](http://www.orangepi.org/orangepizero/) and [wiki link](http://linux-sunxi.org/Xunlong_Orange_Pi_Zero)

The idea is to get them all up and booted from nfs using wifi and one sd card.

Comment: after hours and days of working with initramfs-tools, hook scripts and init scripts I have exhausted my willpower.. I just dont seem to be able to find detailed enough resources to be able to figure this out in this manner.

I will instead try comming at the problem from a different direction.